# The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (19.0.0) is ignored

Tags: android, android-studio

> Warning:The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (19.0.0) is
>   ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (26.0.2) for
>   Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1. Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be
>   used. To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'"
>   from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle
>   Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

What if I want to develop an apk that can work for API 19?
Is there a way without getting errors to compile and test the application easily?

Comment: Either remove that line as it says or use the latest one.

Answer (score 1):

buildToolsVersion is not your App's minimum API support version. You'll want to use `minSdkVersion 19` to support API 19. Generally you'll always want to use the latest build tool version. If you want to test API 19 functionality, download and use the Android 4.4 emulator.